# parsing json from url to swift 2.0

Tags: json, swift

I've been trying to retreive my json data for my iOS App. I tried many different sollutions but none of these worked properly for me. So this was the code I was using to read the json from the url and convert it.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.blind3d.byethost7.com/service.php")!

func load() {
        do {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
            self.handleData(data)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("wieso dont you do siss : \(NSURLRequest(URL: url))")
            self.handleError(error)
        }
    }

func handleError(error : NSError?) {
    print("wieso dont you do siss : \(NSURLRequest(URL: url))")
    NSLog("%@", "Error with loading from \(url): \(error)")
}

func handleData(data : NSData) {
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
        handleJSON(json)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        handleError(error)
    }
}
```

but somehow this isn't running properly. I am always getting this error when I am executing this method: `NSJSONSerialization`

```
Error with loading from http://www.blind3d.byethost7.com/service.php: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
```

The json data I wanted to use for my app is [here](http://www.blind3d.byethost7.com/service.php) 
Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of installed "testCookie-nginx-module"
It's supposed to prevent DDOS attacks on your hosting

When you visit your site for the first time, it sends you this JS code, which your browser is supposed to process and set a special cookie (its name it _test)

Only with this cookie attached to your IP your browser can see the original content (your content: html php json etc.)

Seems the only way for you - is to process this JS (with AES, HEX and other JS functions, get the right _test cookie and send another request with this cookie)

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because there it no actual JSON in the `data` variable. I tried your web service, and this is what you get returned in the `data`, along with all the other error html tags:

```
"This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your
browser or use a browser with Javascript support"
```

The full response:

```html
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("26049265c821fd7227c09955cbb61ebc");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://www.blind3d.byethost7.com/service.php?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

This seems to happen, because there is some Javascript injected in the webpage you are trying to parse from, probably for statistics, or some other unknown reasons.

#### For checking by yourself, print your data - `print(data)`, before calling `self.handleData(data)`

Comment: so.. I've deleted all the stuff on the hoster.. but it was still not working.. If you were me, would you search a new hoster or try to fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is probaly the problem.

Comment: do you know a good hoster, which doesn't add some type of js to the side or something like that?

Comment: The best way is probaly to create a localhost, or try to google for some other free hosts, I am not using free hosts, so I dont know which to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing \r\n or escape them with '\' like

```
\\r\\n
```

and you are good to go. BTW, using json is painful in swift like this, [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) is a necessary library if you deal with json frequently.

Comment: I've removed these chars.. but it's still not working I am still having the same errors as before

Comment: and i am going to add this library.. perhaps this will work then

Comment: Don't forget you still need to change data your server provided.

Comment: Read my answer, the code is OK, the service is not.

Comment: @DejanSkledar is right. I used my browser to open this site with js enabled so I get a json. But even though this json still can't be parsed because of escaping issue.

Comment: @Nero browser is a totally different thing than NSURLConnection and requests in Swift (or any other language)

Comment: @DejanSkledar I realized that I made a mistake to use browser to check what content it have , I mean even if it is a json , it still can't be parsed because of escaping issue .